# the register works fine but the user cannot be able to log in using the same password that they registered with. what might be the issue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

users.js
technologies used

- passport
- passport-local
- bcryptjs
- multer for the profile picture upload

here's the code for the register,log in and the authentication

```
var router = express.Router();
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({dest: './uploads'});
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var User = require('../models/user');

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

router.get('/register', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('register',{title:'Register'});
});

router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('login',{title:'Login'});
});


router.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', {failureRedirect: '/users/login', failureFlash: 'Invalid username or password'}),
   function(req, res) {
  req.flash('success', 'You are now logged in');
  res.redirect('/');
});

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
  User.getUserById(id, function(err, user){
    done(err, user);
  });
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function (username, password, done) {
    User.getUserByUsername(username, function (err, user) {
      if(err) throw err;
      if(!user){
        return done(null, false, {message: 'Unknown user'});
      } 
      User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err,isMatch){
          if(err) return done (err);
          if(isMatch){
            return done(null, user);
          }else {
            return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid Password'});
          }
      });
    });
}));

router.post('/register', upload.single('profilepicture'), function(req, res, next) {
  var name = req.body.name;
  var username = req.body.username;
  var email = req.body.email;
  var password = req.body.password;
  var password2 = req.body.password2;
  var profile = req.body.profilepicture;
  
  if(req.file){
    console.log('uploading...');
  }
  else{
    console.log('not uploaded');
    var profilepicture = 'noimage.jpg';
  }
  //form validator
  req.checkBody('name','Name field is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('email','Email field is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('email','Email is not valid').isEmail();
  req.checkBody('username','Username required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('password','Password cannot be empty').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('password2','Passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);
  //check errors
  var errors = req.validationErrors();
  if(errors){
    res.render('register', {
      errors:errors
    });
  }
  else{
    //var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
    var newUser = new User({
      name:name,
      email:email,
      username: username,
      password:password,
      profilepicture:profilepicture
    });

    User.createUser(newUser,function(err,user){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(user);
    });
  
    req.flash('success', 'You are now registered and can log in');
    res.location('/');
    res.redirect('login');
  }
  
});

router.get('/logout', function (req,res){
  req.logout();
  req.flash('success', 'You are now logged out');
  res.redirect('/users/login');
});

module.exports = router;
```

the user can register successfully and the data gets stored in the database, the password is also hashed but during log in, the text 'Invalid username or password' keeps being displayed.there is no error being displayed just that the user cannot be able to log in even after registering.
what might be the issue?

Comment: Could you please check whether the `User.comparePassword` works correctly?

Comment: one issue is also that you store your password in plain text instead of hashing it

Answer (score 0):

I guess the code `User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err,isMatch){` is comparing plain text password with the encrypted password from the db. Could you please check if both password and user.password are encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

Well you compare your plain password with a plain password in the database. Why should you use `.comparePassword()` if you could just check it with `password === user.password`?

The problem is that you store your password as a plain text in your database. You need to hash it first and you can do it with `bcrypt`

Here replace this with your else block:

```
else {
      // hash the password
      let salt = 12;
      bcrypt.hash(password, salt, function(err, hash) {
        if (err) return res.status(500).json(err);
        //var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
        var newUser = new User({
          name: name,
          email: email,
          username: username,
          password: hash,
          profilepicture: profilepicture
        });
        User.createUser(newUser, function(err, user) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log(user);
        });

        req.flash("success", "You are now registered and can log in");
        res.location("/");
        res.redirect("login");
      });
    }
```

What your compare function do is:

It hashes your plain text password with the salt value thats saved in the hash that you compare. And then it checks if both hashes are the same.